# get number of files modified last month

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to get a count of how many PDFs were created last month.  I'm using the following command but it's returning `0`

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -mtime +46 ! -mtime +30 | wc -l
```

I'm in the correct directory and it seems like the logic is correct... any ideas on why this isn't working?  Is there an easier way, say to pass the specific month I'm looking for instead of trying to calculate days like this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are finding all `pdf` files:

- `46` days ago
- not `30` days ago

  ```
  x>46 && x<=30  --> false
  ```

It will return empty result.

---

```
   Numeric arguments can be specified as
   +n     for greater than n,
   -n     for less than n,
   n      for exactly n.
```

If you want find all `pdf` files (`30<x<46`):

```
$ find . -name '*.pdf' -mtime +30 -mtime -46
```

Comment: [There are 3 kind of "timestamps"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2465/209677): access time (`atime`), change time (`ctime`) and modify time (`mtime`). Why you use `mtime` instead of `ctime`?

Answer (score 9):

If you're using GNU `find` you can specify the absolute dates like this:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -newermt 2012-01-31 ! -newermt 2012-02-29 | wc -l
```

The `-newermt` option will find files that have been modified more recently than an absolute time.

If you're not using GNU, you can use `touch` to create two files with the appropriate timestamps and find your PDFs like this:

```
touch -t 201201312359 oldest # 11:59 PM 1/31/2012
touch -t 201203010000 newest # midnight 3/1/2012
find . -name '*.pdf' -newer oldest ! -newer newest | wc -l
```

See the [GNU documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-g_t_002dnewerXY-24) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This works with 4.3.3+ (January 24, 2009), so not available on older systems (such as RHEL 5).

Answer (score 6):

You appear to be looking for files that are older than 46 days but not older (i.e. younger) than 30 days.

What about this?

```
 find . -name '*.pdf' -mtime -46 -mtime +30
```